# Как изменить стандартный курсор мыши при перетаскивании объекта

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3

Как изменить стандартный курсор мыши при перетаскивании объекта над областью с невозможностью поместить объект:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и над областью с возможностью поместить объект:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример кода: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop2

Comment: В статье рассматривается варианты ответа на ваш вопрос:
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/cursor/

Answer (score 2):

```
onmouseenter="this.style.cursor = 'not-allowed'"
```